# Загрузка данных.

Tags: php, actionscript

PHP код:

```
<?
//header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?>
    <game>
        <gamer>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <login>Игрок 1</login>
            <x>0</x>
            <y>0</y>
            <Rotation>30</Rotation>
        </gamer>
        <player>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <login>Игрок 2</login>
            <lvl>10</lvl>
            <x>570</x>
            <y>570</y>
            <Rotation>0</Rotation>
        </player>
        <player>
            <ID>3</ID>
            <title>Игрок 3</title>
            <lvl>42</lvl>
            <x>200</x>
            <y>200</y>
            <Rotation>'.rand().'</Rotation>
        </player>
    </game>';
    ?>
```

Написал класс на AS3.0 . На локале работал. Потом решил перенести на сайт. Стал настраивать кросполитику. Потом забил, он перестал работать. ХЗ что.. просто нечего не выводит и данные не грузятся.

```
package main
{
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.system.*;

    public class communication
    {
        var loader:URLLoader;
        function communication(){
            Security.loadPolicyFile("http://subdomain2.example/vk_pc/crossdomain.xml");
            loader = new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
            loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
            loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
            loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);

            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://subdomain2.example/vk_pc/game.php");
            try {
                loader.load(request);
            }
            catch (error:SecurityError)
            {
                trace("SecurityError");
            }

        }
        function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void {
            trace("Загружено");
            trace(loader.data);
        }

        private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
            trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
            trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
            trace("progressHandler loaded:" + event.bytesLoaded + " total: " + event.bytesTotal);
        }
    }
}
```

UPD:
ХЗ что исправил но стало писать вот так.
Error opening URL 'http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml'
Error opening URL 'http://subdomain2.example/vk_pc/crossdomain.xml'
Error opening URL 'http://subdomain2.example/vk_pc/game.php'
ioErrorHandler: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Ошибка потока. URL: [http://subdomain2.example/vk_pc/game.php"]](http://subdomain2.example/vk_pc/game.php)
up

Comment: У метода xmlLoaded и конструктора класса, добавьте тег "public/private", а то они странно смотрятся. 
И  catch (error:SecurityError) - я бы заменил на error:Error.

Comment: незнаю что делать. проект сдавать к НГ, а из-за этого нечего не выходит...

Comment: - то что указано, сделано?

- просто в браузере хмл грузится?

- наружу, в инет, можно открыть сервер? попробую у себя

Comment: да. заменил.
Да грузится.
нет. нельзя. пишит You don't have permission to access /vk_pc/game.php on this server

Comment: "You don't have permission" - так может с этим разобраться, и все заработает

Comment: с этим разобрался. Но не помогло. Тем более флешь подключался по локалке, а не по внешней...
Хочу добавить что сокеты подключаются отлично.

Comment: Так как вы разобрались, если наружу не работает сервер?

Comment: я переставил апачи.